# Accessing Azure DevOps Git file directly from Azure Databricks

Tags: python, apache-spark, azure-devops, azure-databricks, azure-repos

We have a CSV file stored in a ADO (Azure DevOps) Git repository. I have Azure Databricks cluster running, and in the workspace I have a python code to read and transform this CSV file into a spark dataframe. But every time the file undergoes change,  I have to manually download it from ADO Git and upload to the Databricks workspace. I use the following command to verify that the file has been uploaded:-

```
dbutils.fs.ls ("/FileStore/tables")
```

It lists my file. I then use the following Python code to convert this CSV to Spark dataframe:

```
file_location = "/FileStore/tables/MyFile.csv"
file_type = "csv"
# CSV options
infer_schema = "true"
first_row_is_header = "true"
delimiter = ","
# The applied options are for CSV files. For other file types, these will be ignored.
df = spark.read.format(file_type) \
  .option("inferSchema", infer_schema) \
  .option("header", first_row_is_header) \
  .option("sep", delimiter) \
  .load(file_location)
```

So there is this manual step involved every time the file in the ADO Git repository changes. Is there any Python function using which I can directly point to the copy of the file in the master branch of the ADO Git ?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choices, depending on what would be simpler for you:

1. Use [Azure DevOps Python API](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api) to access [file (called item in API)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) inside the Git tree.  Because this file will be accessed only from driver node, then you will need to use `dbutils.fs.cp` to copy file from driver node into `/FileStore/tables`
2. Setup a build pipeline inside your Git repository, that will be triggered only on commit of specific file, and if it changes, use [Databricks CLI](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/index.html) (`databrics fs cp ...` command) to copy file directly into DBFS.  Here is an [example](https://github.com/alexott/databricks-cicd-definitelynotademo/blob/master/azure-pipelines.yml) that not doing exactly what you want, but it could be used as inspiration.